# How to hide CSS Elements by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, css, typeerror, addeventlistener

I am building a Chrome Web Extension that hides parts of Youtube's home page at the click of a button.

I am trying to hide CSS elements after the webpage loads after clicking a button on my Chrome extension's popup.

I am not able to use inline CSS and must use javascript due to chrome's security protocols.

when I click the button on the popup, I received the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"

HTML:

`<button id="hideRecommended">Hide Recommended</button>`

Javascript:

```
let homePage = document.querySelector(".style-scope.ytd-rich-grid-renderer#primary");
document.querySelector(".hideRecommended").addEventListener("click",showHideHomePage);
function showHideHomePage(){
    homePage.style.display="none";
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any input would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1):

Since you are define the button by `id` as follows

```
<button id="hideRecommended">Hide Recommended</button>
```

So change

```
document.querySelector(".hideRecommended").addEventListener("click",showHideHomePage);
```

To

```
document.querySelector("#hideRecommended").addEventListener("click",showHideHomePage);
```

Note:

- `.hideRecommended` measn select by `class`
- `#hideRecommended` means
  select by `id`